# Select multiple items using multiple keys from a Map in Elixir

Tags: elixir

I am trying to implement the [Modbus](http://modbus.org) protocol in Elixir as an exercise to learn Elixir and to further my understanding of Functional Programming.

Modbus data is modeled as contiguous blocks of registers. A modbus read request takes the form of . This instructs the server to collect the registers starting at  and continuing up for  registers. For example, if  was 0 and  was 5, the server would return the values of registers 0, 1, 2, 3, and 4.

I am thinking that a good data structure for modeling these registers is a map where the key is the register and the value is the value of the register. Therefore, I am curious if there is an idiomatic way to retrieve multiple values from a map given multiple keys, without having to iterate through the keys and calling get() for each key.

I would be open to other suggestions for a better data model, if the map isn't really appropriate.

Python has [itemgetter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) in the operator module to perform this task. Maybe that will give another clue for what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: where are your codes? please post them here.

Comment: I was thinking this was more of a philosophy question rather than a problem with code. I can edit my question with some code but it will take a little while to put it together.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[`Map#take/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Map.html#take/2) would do:

```
iex(1)> data = %{a: 42, b: 3.14, foo: :bar}
iex(2)> data |> Map.take(~W|a foo|a) 
%{a: 42, foo: :bar}
```

On the other hand, your data looks and quacks more like [`Keyword` list](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Keyword.html):

```
iex(3)> data = [a: 42, b: 3.14, foo: :bar]
iex(4)> data |> Keyword.take([:a, :foo]) 
[a: 42, foo: :bar]
```

It’s up to you to pick any of above, or even provide your own struct with handy methods to retrieve subsets.

Comment: I think Map.take is exactly what I needed. I am so used to OO languages that I was searching in the wrong part of the docs. I really appreciate the pointers. Also, I don't think Keyword lists will do it for me because the Key needs to be a register number, not an atom.